# Missing attribute `value` for equal ctypes array objects

Tags: python, arrays, attributes, ctypes, attributeerror

I know 2 ways of creating a c array out of a python sequence `data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

Creating an array class, initializing it and passing the values through the `value` attribute:

```
array_type = ctypes.c_int * len(data)
array1 = array_type()
array1.value = data
```

Creating an array class and passing the value as arguments during initialization:

```
array_type = ctypes.c_int * len(data)
array2 = array_type(*data)
# Or 'array2 = (ctypes.c_int * len(data))(*data)'
```

Both generates the same type:

```
>>> array1
<c_int_Array_6 object at 0x1031d9510>
>>> array2
<c_int_Array_6 object at 0x1031d9400>
```

But when trying to access the value attribute:

```
array1.value
>>> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
array2.value
>>> AttributeError: 'c_int_Array_6' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Why doesn't `array2` has a `value` attribute? My understanding is that these arrays are the same type but just initialized differently.

---

And even if I create two different arrays with two different values, the problem still occurs:

```
char_array = (c_char * 4)(*data)
print(char_array.value)  # Works!

int_array = (c_int * 4)(*data)
print(int_array.value)  # Doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `array1.value` as `data`. But you didn't specifically define `array2.value`. By default `.value` is not define (even if the array contains the values).

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> # Same commands that you provide
>>> # ...
>>> array1.value
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> array2.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'c_int_Array_6' object has no attribute 'value'

>>> list(array2)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> array2[0]
1

>>> data_bis = (1,4,5)
>>> array2.value = data_bis
>>> array2
<__main__.c_int_Array_6 object at 0x7f86dc981560>
>>> array2.value
(1, 4, 5)
```

As you can see, you can still have access to the values of `array2` using standard python call for list.

You can have a look at Python's documentation, especially on [fundamental data types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) and on [arrays and pointers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#arrays-and-pointers).

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid now... Arrays doesn't have the attribute `value`, it's the individual data types that has. And by doing `array1.value = data` I dynamically added that attribute. In the `ctypes.create_string_buffer` function they did it the way I showcased first which made me assume `value` was an existing attribute to an array, not dynamically created. Thanks, it makes sense now!

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes we can't see the obvious, just glad I was able to help you!

Comment: Wait, I knew it was more complicated than that. Just did some tests and the attribute `value` is defined for arrays when doing `char_array = (c_char * 4)(*data)` but not `int_array = (c_int * 4)(*data)`. So the attribute does exists when the array is of a certain data type. I've searched the documentation but couldn't find anything about this behaviour. Is this well-known behaviour and I'm just missing something obvious?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman My first guess would be: `Array`type does not have `value` attribute. But `char` type are considered as string and not array. `i = c_int(42) ; i.value` returns 42, but `j = c_int() * 10; j.value` returns an error (no attribute 'value'). If you replace `c_int` by `c_char` in the previous examples, then it works. But indeed there is nothing in the documentation about that.

Comment: It only seems to work for `c_char` and `c_wchar`, so it sounds reasonable. I'll assume that's the case for time being. Thanks again!